# Estimation Procedure of Multilevel Logistic Regression

Tags: self-study, logistic, references, multilevel-analysis, lme4-nlme

I know the estimation procedure for logistic regression is the iterative weighted least squares method.

In the book *An Introduction to Generalized Linear Models* written by Dobson & Barnett, in chapter 7, they described how to estimate parameters of logistic regression by an example.

I am looking something like that (including example) for the Estimation Procedure of multilevel logistic regression.

Can you please give me online reference for the topic?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156465/estimating-multilevel-logistic-regression-models?rq=1